# Multiple backgrounds not showing in Safari (mobile/desktop)

Tags: css

I have multiple backgrounds on my `body` element.

```
body { background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%, rgba(182,176,157, .5) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de }
```

It shows up fine in the latest versions of IE, FF, and Chrome. However, neither of the two backgrounds show up in Safari.

[Here is the site.](http://keebs.com/sandbox)

Can someone help me point out where I went wrong?

Edit: Tried this but it didn't work.

```
body {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%, rgba(182,176,157, .5) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%, rgba(182,176,157, .5) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    }
```

Edit 2: Tried this but it also didn't work. Neither background shows for any browser now.

```
body {
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    }
```

Edit 3: This is what the rest of my body code looks like.

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%),url("images/flower-bg.jpg") repeat #eae7de;
    color:#544a46;
    font:62.5%/1.6 Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif
    }
```

Comment: which browser are you using on desktop?

Comment: @Kees It shows up fine for me in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE. I just checked Safari and it doesn't show in the desktop version, either. Oops, I'll add that detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `background-image:` instead

Try this code:

```
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg'); /*fallback*/
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg'), linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%);
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg'), -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%);
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg'), -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%);
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg'), -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%);
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg'), -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 10%, rgb(183,176,157) 100%);
```

Comment: I added this but it's still not showing. By the way, I forgot `background` in the original post so I added it in along with the code I added.

Comment: How would I add in the url for the flower image?

Comment: Just ,url('yourimage.png'); behind it. should work. same as you did in your code.

Comment: I tried this but it also didn't work. Neither background shows up now for any browser. I added the code I used in the post above.

Comment: The image shows up now in all browsers. But it looks like the gradient isn't showing because it's "below" the image.